# Inline action with 2 permissions/authorizations

Tags: eosio-code, eosiocpp

I have 3 accounts:

1. Contract Account.
2. Storage Account.
3. Recipient Account.

I made a smart contract to give out tokens from `Storage Account` to the `Recipient Account` using a `claim` function from the `Contract` Account.

Current error I'm getting is `Error: missing authority of {Storage Account}`.

I've already given eosio.code permission to Contract Account.

I'm guessing the fix to this problem is to add 2 permissions/authorizations to the `claim` function of the smart contract but I don't know how to do that.

[image]

Comment: Have you been able to solve this? I'm facing a similar issue.

Comment: Try asking here: https://t.me/joinchat/0uhWYfXVpPlkNTA1

Comment: Hi @soulseekah not yet, still wondering how to do this, I asked on the telegram channel provided above but one of the volunteers were kinda toxic so went out right away

Comment: can you pls post here the link to the telegram channel with your post in that dev telegram channel? I tried to find it but I couldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can send a vector of permissions instead just one:

https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eosio.cdt/latest/structeosio_1_1action#function-action-33

however, did you try to send just the Storage Permission instead of what you are sending now?

Comment: Hi, I'm really late to reply to you.

Sorry about that, I haven't done that yet as I've made a different way of handling this which is adding the tokens to the actual contract's account, giving the contract code account active permission and allowing it to directly do transfers on behalf of its own account. Not sure if I made sense but that's how I solved the problem I had. 

I think this is kinda the same as what you said just in the sense that i had used the contract itself to do transfers. Do you think this is okay? Thanks!

Comment: that works as well, so you eliminated the storage account from equation.